# Concatenation with Blade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to access a table column in my ItemController. In this instance, I wish to use the values in my array + a concatenated string to for the column name.

ItemController.php
        ....

```
public function displayItems() {
   $itemsList = array('Alpha','Bravo','Charlie','Delta');
   //$results = returned mysql row here
   return view('items', ['rs' => $results, 'items' => $itemsList]);
}
```

page.blade.php

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
  //$item is used elsewhere too, so keep $item
  {{$rs->$item.'_data'}}
@endforeach
```

Desired output:

```
$rs->Alpha_data;
$rs->Delta_data;
etc
```

How can I dynamically set a variable for $rs->**name** ?

Comment: Shot in the dark: Try `{{ $rs->${$item.'_data'} }}`

Comment: @Ashley - this is completely none value added, but your $itemsList looks like ramp names! If they are, few people will get it.

Comment: @TimStrawbridge Nothing to do with ramps as far as I remember. I literally just wrote random values as pseudo code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
{{ $rs->${$item.'_data'} }}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: What would be the best way to also call `strtolower()` on `$item.'_data'`  ?

Comment: Try `{{ $rs->${strtolower($item).'_data'} }}`.

Comment: i have something like this. $category->category->category->name
and how do i concatenate like this {{ $rs->${$item.'_data'} }}
thanks if any answer on time.

Answer (score 3):

lets say you are retrieving a single record 'task', and this record has variables called 'var1','var2','var3' ... all the way to 'var16'.

you can echo those variables in your blade file like so:

```
@for($y=1; $y<=16; $y++)
 {{ $task->{'var'.$y} }}
@endfor
```

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple, just use the . sign for concats in PHP

Comment: The . for concatenation is already used in the original post. Joining the strings itself is not the issue here as you can see with the accepted answer. As this answer does not really address this questions problems, you might want to remove it.